# Prime twins $ (3^n - 2, 3^n - 4) $ conjecture

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers, exponentiation, conjectures, twin-primes

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

Conjecture

There are infinitely many prime twins of the form

$$ ( 3^n - 2, 3^n - 4) $$

Examples include

$$(3^2 - 2,3^2 - 4) = ( 7,5 ) $$
$$ ( 3^{37} - 2 , 3^{37} - 4 ) $$
$$ ( 3^{41} - 2 , 3^{41} - 4 ) $$

Notice $2,37,41$ are primes themselves.
Coincidence ?

This resembles conjectures about prime twins , fermat primes and mersenne primes. 
So I do not expect a proof :)
I already know the typical statistical arguments why this should be false ( zeta(2) type sums as expected amount ) , so I Will not ask for that either.

My mentor believes this.

How many values are known apart from these ?
Are there equivalent conjectures known ?

Is a disproof possible ? 
I was not able to disprove it. 
I tried mod arguments.

Any ideas ?

Comment: “ Tommy’s radical twin conjecture “ :)

Comment: I trust you understand that since those primes are $2$ apart, if you could prove the conjecture you would prove the twin prime conjecture.

Comment: Yes Ethan. So the focus is on a potential disproof.

Comment: Given the existence of fairly large examples, I doubt there is any simple proof of finiteness (which would probably be based on congruences).

Comment: It's not entirely coincidence.  If $n$ is even, then $3^n-4$ is a difference of squares and so can't be prime.

Comment: Note that the number between twin primes of the stated form will be $3^n-3=3(3^{n-1}-1)$. Twin primes (other than $3,5$) always have the form $6k\pm 1$ which in this instance would be $6\cdot \frac{(3^{n-1}-1)}{2} \pm 1$

Comment: Checking up to $n = 6000$, the only ones I found were for $n = 2, 5, 37, 41$. That doesn't mean the conjecture is false - there might just be a large gap.

Comment: Of relevance are [this OEIS sequence](http://oeis.org/A014224) and [this one](http://oeis.org/A058959). These support the conclusion that there is no other twin prime pair of that form (at least with $n \le 312155$.

Comment: Since $3^n$ grows exponential , I would strongly conjecture a finite number of twins of this form. I have not yet calculated the "expected number of such twins" , maybe someone can do this. I expect a finite number. This would at least be a heuristic. A proof or disproof of this conjecture seems to be out of reach.